# Iptables - having trouble opening port 443

Tags: ssl, https, iptables

I am attempting to set up https, but I am having difficulty opening that port.

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000073s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https
```

Here is my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Sep 18 03:42:22 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [21660:1221924]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 18 03:42:22 2012
```

(And I ran `service iptables restart` with no errors)

I would really appreciate some quick help :)

(iptables -S gives pretty much the same output as above):

```
[root@weather-bell ~]# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[root@weather-bell ~]#
```

Comment: modified question

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -ntl | grep 443` and `iptables -nvL`.

Comment: what OS? have you tried ufw allow 443?

Comment: Wait, what? Just noticed that you're scanning from localhost (`Nmap scan report for localhost`). I.e. the loopback rule (`-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`) is the only one that matters in the iptables config. Are you sure anything listens on localhost:443?